# “How to fix ‘NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil’ error in Android Robolectric”

Tags: java, android, androidx, android-maps-utils

I migrated my android project to AndroidX with Android Studio, but now I have an error when I launch my Units tests with Robolectric : 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil'
But 'com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil' exists, I can use this import in my file.

I tried to 
  - upgrade gradle to the latest version 5.1.1
  - clean, delete cache, restart Android Studio
  - upgrade Robolectric and maps librairies

Here is my test function :

```java
    @Test
    public void launchGeographicRestrictionEditionActivity() {
        ActivityController<GeographicRestrictionEditionActivity> controller = Robolectric.buildActivity(GeographicRestrictionEditionActivity.class);
        geographicRestrictionEditionActivity = controller.create()
                .start()
                .resume()
                .visible()
                .get();

        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getRemoteContext(null);

        Assert.assertNotNull(geographicRestrictionEditionActivity);
    }
```

Here is my error when I launch the test :

```java
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil

    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzbz.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzd(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.createDelegate(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onInflate(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1493)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManagerImpl.java:3174)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:186)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:772)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at com.deveryware.notico.mapsnew.DeverywareMapFragment.onCreateView(DeverywareMapFragment.java:148)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2612)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:874)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1228)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1293)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2646)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2600)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
    at com.deveryware.notico.widget.DeverywareActivity.onStart(DeverywareActivity.java:159)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1334)
    at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnStart(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:686)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7029)
    at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers$6.run(ReflectionHelpers.java:247)
    at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.traverseClassHierarchy(ReflectionHelpers.java:399)
    at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethod(ReflectionHelpers.java:241)
    at org.robolectric.android.controller.ComponentController$1.run(ComponentController.java:53)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:396)
    at org.robolectric.android.controller.ComponentController.invokeWhilePaused(ComponentController.java:50)
    at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.start(ActivityController.java:126)
    at com.deveryware.notico.myUnitTests.ui.map.MapFragmentTests.launchGeographicRestrictionEditionActivity(MapFragmentTests.java:45)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:256)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is my code in my project which causing problem : inflater

```java
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(getMapLayoutResId(), container, false);
.......
```

I would like to launch the tests without this error pls.

Comment: I would be surprised if you can unit test code that depends upon the Play Services SDK. You may need to switch to instrumented tests for this.

Comment: Hello, thanks, I can unit test code that depends upon the play services SDK before but now with the migration this error appears ....

Comment: Not sure if it's related but I was getting a similar error after upgrading to AndroidX and the fix was to upgrade my `com.google.android.gms:play-services` dependencies from `11.8` to `17.0`. Hopefully that helps others.